# Why are my if-else statements being ignored?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to create some code that reads a textfile, splits up the text file into smaller chunks, and performs actions depending on what some of the chunks equal to. Here is my example text file.

```
Derek 19 12
Jake 17 1
God 5000 13
```

The issue that I am running into is that my if-else statements are being completely ignored and only the else statement at the end is being called upon. I would appreciate it if someone could help me to understand what i am doing wrong. Here is my code(The text file and the code shown are simplified versions of a much larger program that i am working on. I have tested the code to make sure that the error is still there). Any help that anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

```
package testProgram;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IfElseStatmentTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "NumberData.txt";
    Scanner inputStream = ReadInputFile(fileName);
    while (inputStream.hasNextLine()){
        String newLine = inputStream.nextLine();
        String[] data = newLine.split(" ");
        if (data[0] == "Derek")
            System.out.println("Hi Derek");
        else if (data[0] == "Jake")
            System.out.println("Hi Jake");
        else if (data[0] == "God")
            System.out.println("Hi God");
        else
            System.out.println("kaboom");
    }

}

public static Scanner ReadInputFile(String fileName){

    Scanner inputStream = null;

   try {
       inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
       return inputStream;
   }
   //display an error message if you have trouble opening the file             
   catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
       System.out.println("Error opening the file " + 
                           fileName);

       System.exit(0);
       return inputStream;
   }

    }

}
```

Here is the incorrect output that I am getting

```
kaboom
kaboom
kaboom
```

Here is the output that i am supposed to be getting.

```
Hi Derek
Hi Jake
Hi God
```

Comment: You need to do `.equals()`, not `==`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16194428/2587908

Comment: When comparing strings, instead of "x" == "y" you should use equals() or equalsIgnoreCase()

Comment: Excellent, the code worked. Thank you for the help!